# How to evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, chain-rule

I'm having trouble understanding how  $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2x =2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Please show as many steps of the proof as necessary so that I can apply this to other problems.

*Thank you for your time~! ^_^*

Comment: You should say what $y$ represents (or if @A.Γ. 's edit is what you meant).

Comment: It could help to understand defining $q(y) = y^2$ and then using the chain rule on $\frac d{dx}q\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: sorry I don't understand either of these comments, unless they are addressing my original error in the title of writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ instead of $\frac{d}{dx}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2x= 2\sin(x)(\sin(x))'= 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this middle step...

Comment: diffrentiation of $x^n$ would be $n*x^{n-1}*(x)' = n*x^{n-1}*1$ right? same principle.

Comment: what's confusing me is the $^2$ comes before the $x$ in $sin^2x$

Comment: are you able to add another step or two before the middle step?

Comment: i'm sorry i cant that really is the first step.

Comment: Why does $sin^nx = (sinx)^n$? It just does?

Comment: thats just a way to write it.

Comment: choose witch ever you like.

Comment: [Looks like it is just a rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1444526/564770), with this in mind everything makes much more sense. Thanks again for your help everyone!

Answer (score 4):

We have that by the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule),
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x)\sin(x))\\&=
(\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x))\sin(x)+\sin(x)(\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x))\\&=
\cos(x)\sin(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x)\\&=2\sin(x)\cos(x).\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!

Comment: @RyanEvans It is correct. The only problem that it does not use the chain rule, so you cannot apply it to other problems in general.

Comment: @A.Γ. ah.. good point..

Comment: @RyanEvans If the middle step in Chris2006's answer is unclear then it is important to learn how the chain rule works and train it out. It is one of the major principles in derivation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{d(\sin^nx)}{dx}=\dfrac{d(\sin^nx)}{d(\sin x)}\cdot\dfrac{d(\sin x)}{dx}=?$$

**See** [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: Why are we able to $u$ as $sin (x)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have a composite function
$$
x\quad\color{red}{\longrightarrow}\quad u=\sin x\quad\color{blue}{\longrightarrow}\quad y=u^2.
$$

1. The derivative of $u\color{blue}\to u^2$ is $2u$, but $u=\sin x$, then it is $\color{blue}{2\sin x}$.
2. The derivative of $x\color{red}\to\sin x$ is $\color{red}{\cos x}$.

The chain rule says: take their product
$$
\color{blue}{2\sin x}\cdot\color{red}{\cos x}.
$$

Comment: Apologies, I am unfamiliar with this ⟶ notation.

Comment: @RyanEvans It means "maps to", a convenient way to think of a mapping. $y=f(x)$ can be written as $x\to y$, that is, you take $x$ and construct $y$ of it.

Answer (score 1):

**With bare hands:**

$$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos2x}2$$ so that

$$(\sin^2x)'=-\frac12(-2\sin2x)=\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x.$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a function $(f(x))^n$ is given by

$$ ((f(x))^n)' = \frac{d (f(x))^n }{ d f(x)} \frac{d f(x)}{dx} = n f(x)^{n-1} f'(x), $$

by the chain rule.

Hence for your example $(f(x))^2 = (\sin(x))^2$ and the derivative is

$$\left((\sin(x))^2 \right)' = 2 \sin(x) \cdot (\sin(x))' = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x). $$

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of the derivative and the general theorem $\lim(fg)=(\lim f)(\lim g)$ provided $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ both exist, we have

$$\begin{align}
{d\over dx}\sin^2x
&=\lim_{y\to x}{\sin^2x-\sin^2y\over x-y}\\
&=\left(\lim_{y\to x}(\sin x+\sin y)\right)\left(\lim_{y\to x}{\sin x-\sin y\over x-y} \right)\\
&=(\sin x+\sin x)\left({d\over dx}\sin x\right)\\
&=2\sin x\cos x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{{\rm d}(\sin^2 x)}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{{\rm d}(\sin^2 x)}{{\rm d}(\sin x)}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}(\sin x)}{{\rm d}x}=2\sin x \cos x.$$